# Trying to replace my old kitchen gas stove, how to find a replacement?

Tags: kitchens, stove

I've got an old kitchen gas stove which is built-in the ceramics on my kitchen. It's shape used to be popular in the 90s (rounded corners), however it seems as though these days all stoves come in a rectangular shape. How can I find a gas stove in the same shape to replace my old one? Attached is a photo of my current gas stove.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MAybe you can try with a marine one [like one](http://www.cansrl.com/en/marine/stoves_4/flush-fitting_37.html). Or maybe some vintage/antique seller like [this one](http://www.dreamstoves.com) could have one, try asking.

However, I believe that if you want to modernize your kitchen, you'll need a new shape. All that you will find in this shape will likely be vintage.

Alternatively, what would happen if you just put a square/rectangle one on top of the hole?

Hole:

[image]

New square fitting:

[image]

Added on top:

[image]

Finally add some (fake) marble to hide the space below the corners:

[image]